# NumPy/Pandas: convert array of "steps" into bool mask

Tags: pandas, numpy, vectorization

I have an array like this:

```
arr = np.array([4, 6, 3, 9, 2, 100, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1])
```

I want to convert it to a bool array like this:

```
[ T, F, F, F, T,   F, T, F, F, T, T]
# 4, 6, 3, 9, 2, 100, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1
```

I can do it with a loop like this:

```
mask = np.zeros(len(arr), dtype=bool)
ii = 0
while ii < len(arr):
    mask[ii] = True
    ii += arr[ii]
```

It's sort of an indirect indexing scheme, where each element in the input tells us how many subsequent elements are invalid.

How can I do it without using a Python loop, so that it will be fast if the input array is large?  I'm happy to use Pandas too.

Comment: If I understand correctly, this is already efficient (jumping to the next index and changing) and I can't imagine a vector operation would improve on this... I also doubt `numpy`, `Pandas` or `scipy` has an intrinsic for this but a simple alternative would be to write in c/c++, wrap in `ctypes` and pass `numpy` arrays to your function.

Comment: @EdSmith: the loop code is not efficient for the simple reason that it uses the Python interpreter to loop over the values.  If you have a lot of data, this can take a lot of time.

Comment: I meant algorithmically if this was written in a low level language it would be optimal in the current form (appears to be non-vectorizable)? In which case, the question is would reappropriating some `numpy`/`pandas` routine be faster than the python interpreter overhead.

Comment: @EdSmith: If we can find an appropriate set of routines in NumPy or Pandas, it will almost certainly be much faster.  That's the assumption built into this question--and I think it's a safe one.

Comment: I don't think this is verctorizable as the next step of the loop depends (what you execute) on a previous step. Your next index `ii` depends on what you computed on the previous step.

Answer (score 2):

There may be some vectorization trick I'm not thinking of, but if you can use `numba`, it's well suited for problems like this - this loop should now be very fast.

```
import numba

@numba.jit(nopython=True)
def jump_mask(arr):
    mask = np.zeros(len(arr), dtype=np.bool_)
    ii = 0
    while ii < len(arr):
        mask[ii] = True
        ii += arr[ii]
    return mask
```

Comment: I know about Numba but I was hoping not to need it for this.  Usually these sorts of operations can be "pivoted" somehow using NumPy alone.

Comment: Yeah, I understand trying to avoid an extra dependency, but I can't think of a way to get the "skips" with just numpy/pandas ops, though may be possible.  You're probably aware, but this would be straightforward in cython too.